# MySQL from Silverlight on Linux Server

Tags: mysql, silverlight

I'm trying to access a MySQL database through Silverlight, and I know you can't do it directly, but the only way I know of is to use a WCF service. This won't run on the server I have, is there any other way to access the database (through PHP maybe)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access the db through any kind of webservice (not just WCF).  The language you develop the service in is immaterial to silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something like that without using WCF. Instead, I have created an ASP.Net page that grabs the requested data, formats it into a JSON "string", then returns it to Silverlight.